# Should present or past tense be used for "Enable / Enabled" checkboxes?

Tags: toggle, checkboxes, labels

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should a toggle button show its current state or the state to which it will change?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/should-a-toggle-button-show-its-current-state-or-the-state-to-which-it-will-chang)

When a checkbox enables a feature, is it more correct to use Enable [] or Enabled []?

Basically should the tense be present to indicate the what the check action does - checking it enables it - or should it be past to indicate the state of the feature - if it is checked then the feature is enabled?

Comment: And we're back to this :). Please see [this question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/should-a-toggle-button-show-its-current-state-or-the-state-to-which-it-will-chang) and [this one](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5069/should-toggle-buttons-show-what-they-do-or-the-system-status).

Comment: Ah, yup those answer the question.  Didn't find them searching for checkbox tense.  If you write that up as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Glad I could help. I'll just close this one as duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

I would be inclined to use future tense. If a UI element will change an option, it's not in the past, it's in the future, and it also makes sense from a grammatical perspective.

```
[x] Enable giant lasers
[x] Enable warp drive
```

Similar to:

```
[x] Show galaxies
[x] Show constellations
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a check mark should be used in a form that needs to be submitted, I always thought of that control as specifying the state that will be set when the form is submitted. I know there's no guarantee that it's actually being used that way, but I think it still makes sense. So, use "Enabled" with a check box, and "Enable" on an actual toggle button.