# What toggle button should represent - state or action?

Tags: buttons, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should a toggle button show its current state or the state to which it will change?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/should-a-toggle-button-show-its-current-state-or-the-state-to-which-it-will-chan)

I know there was [similar question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/should-a-toggle-button-show-its-current-state-or-the-state-to-which-it-will-chan) to mine already, but I have something new to ask.
I have a button which toggles between view and edit mode. The title on a button outlines the action user will perform once he click on it:

[image]

The problem is what to do with icons. What icon should represent - current state or an action user will perform once he click on it again? I don't want to have inconsistency neither with button title, neither with content mode.

Comment: I think your icons are mixed around currently they way they stand.  If the icon isn't part of the button, then maybe they are ok, showing current state.  But as you have them, I would be confused.

Comment: I don't see how this is a different question to the one you have linked to?

Comment: The difference is what icons should represent - state or action?

Comment: I think you're answering your own question when you ask "state or action". Should probably include both; however, in very different ways :]

Comment: This question too: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20713/toggle-buttons-turn-on-vs-enable

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate. Just because it's an icon and not a button it's still the same question. However if I'm mistaken then you can elaborate on your question by editing it and if it is suitably distinct from the linked question we can re-open it for you.

Comment: I believe that since an action _will_ be performed, the icon should represent the state that it will be in once the action has been performed. I.e. If the button says "Unlock" and I want to unlock something, then the icon should show an unlocked lock. That's just what I think, anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [The Humane Interface](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201379376) by Jef Raskin, he argues that the best way to ensure that the user knows both **what state they are in** and **what they can do is** to avoid modes (e.g. locked mode, unlocked mode). This means instead of toggling between locked and unlocked buttons, show buttons for both--one that is on and that one is off. Although you lose in space savings of one button, you gain by removing action ambiguity for the user.

Comment: I wonder what showing both buttons solves. [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zltxC.png) I have absolutely no clue.