# How to present 3 options: not selected, selected, locked

Tags: navigation, selection, features

I'm working on consistent way to show 3 types of tests user can choose from.

One type of test is always active (user is doing this test).

Options are:

- Flashcard Test (not selected)
- Guessing Test (selected)
- Writing Test (locked, user should be encouraged to unlock it by buying premium account)

[image: Test options]

Currently it looks very weak and misleading because Writing test looks like half active and half inactive because of green CTA text.

Any ideas how to achieve those 2 goals?

1. user knows which type of test is currently selected
2. user is aware that writing test is a premium feature and should click to unlock it.

Answer (score 4):

I see several aspects in your proposal that I would solve differently.

1. **"Flash cards" appears disabled, but is actually a valid option.**
   That option currently appears as disabled as your "locked" option. I'd color all available options black, not gray, to avoid that.
2. **Show clearly which option is currently selected.**
   It's always a challenge to show which one of two options is actually selected (see also [my answer here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/46207/how-to-highlight-the-selected-option-when-there-are-only-2-elements/46213#46213)). Even though things will get clearer in your example once a user goes "pro" and more options become available, I would consider using a visual indicator to avoid any guessing. As an example, I've used a white box&arrow in my mockup below.
3. **Separate advertisement from the rest.**
   Since you seem to offer some functions of your service for free, some not, I would make that a clear statement. It makes the ad more prominent, for sure, but your users do get something for free after all. Making the add more prominent **also helps you to better sell the for-pay aspect of your service**. For example. in your case, you could **show some benefits of the currently locked tests as well** (might be those "points x" lines, I'm not sure). You can use these to convince your customers to go "pro".
4. A minor point really: you've used the "unlock" icon to indicate that an option is actually locked.

So, to summarize, here's **how all of this could add up**:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiomlq.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Andreas, this is something I was looking for. It is now very consistent, with clear value proposition. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool, great I could be of help! Make sure you upvote and/or mark-as-answer the replies you like, *if* you've found it useful. Sorry for putting it so bluntly, but it helps us and also earns you more reputation points (i.e. marking as answer does - http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me, in your case :

- Selected text should be colored
- Standard text should be black
- Locked text should be gray

Maybe could you display the "Go Pro" text in green only when the user hover your text.