# Would you consider this button to represent that the device is currently on or off?

Tags: buttons

Would you consider this button to represent that the device is currently on or off? The opacity switches to the other button once it is tapped. I just want to make sure that the state is fairly clear.[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Romeo! This question appears to be off topic because it doesn't really use the expertise of the people on this site. **Instead of asking people who run usability tests to act as test participants, why not just create your own impromptu test at your office?**  You could flash the above in a meeting and have people raise their hands to say which state they think it's in.  If there's a difference in opinions, you know you need to redesign it.

Comment: If you are interested in the problem in general have a look at this question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/should-a-toggle-button-show-its-current-state-or-the-state-to-which-it-will-chan

Comment: @3nafish I tried getting opinions but I wanted a larger sample from different people so the sample is more conclusive. I think it relates to UX because that will be a switch in the app and I do not want users to be confused as to which the current state of the controlled appliance is.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear to me. It doesn't tell me the state, or even that it's a button.

Comment: This is just a small part from a bigger page. It is very clear to the user that it is a button and what it does. The only thing that might be confusing is the current state, if it is currently on or off.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a compelling reason to use English text rather than the ubiquitous power on/off symbol? This could be rendered in such a way as to indicate power on or off.

[image]

You've then reduced the button set to a single button with 2 states.

Comment: Just for design reasons.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a button for make an action Its important define and show the context of this button and its consecuences if the user submit it. Buttons by itself not show anything, only the text in the box.

Asked youurself:

- What is the option enabled or disabled this button? (on, off)
- What is the action of these buttons and your consecuences? (turn on/off the application, the mobile, the 3g...)

You can see this image like example. 
[Switch buttons example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Y9v.png)

In that image you can see what is the meaning of submit every buttons, the context of this buttons, what it will happen if I touch something, etc
Your buttons not bad (maybe you could considere some shadow effect...)but its important define the context and the consecuences.