# Android - combining a check mark in a button

Tags: android

I'd like to show a big button, indicating the current state of a view and some kind of a hint to what will happen when clicked.

Some combination between a regular button and a checkbox - a button with a check mark.

For example, a button to indicate if the air conditioner is working:

```
-------------
| Works | V |
-------------
-------------
| Works | O |
-------------
```

**Any idea where I can find such a pattern?** Specifically in Android.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at.....what do the v and o mean?

Comment: @tohster - on or off. True or false.

Answer (score 1):

I like Facebook's pattern:

[image]  [image]

Mine would probably be to just change the text from `Like` to `On`.

See a more complete answer [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/75413/63697).

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you want an on/off switch to toggle the state of the AC. Sorry if i miss-interpreted the question.

I'd recommend the use of an on/off label as this is controlling its running state rather than a setting among many, like 'Silent mode' or similar for your AC. You can localize the label if needed rather than using I|O label.

Check the [Android - ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html) for how to implement this.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for something that keeps the same notion, but indicates a different state in that notion. On/Off toggle button changes the text. I'd like the text to not change and stay at the same notion. I'd like only for the state indication to change.

Comment: It's up to you to define the text for the on vs off labels for the ´ToggleButton´. You can have it say 'Working' on both states if that's what you want.

Comment: Recommended link on the topic: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/should-a-toggle-button-show-its-current-state-or-the-state-to-which-it-will-chan?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

There is no such pattern in Android, but, Android allows you to modify existing UI-elements.

Check out [this article](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/05/20/create-custom-toggle-button-android/). You would have to create 2 "button/togglebutton-combination" where it's clear whether it's selected or not. It's the same as the article I referenced to, except your images would be different :)