# Is a switcher a better pattern than radio buttons?

Tags: radio-buttons

I'm designing a list with an option to switch some records on and off. I'm wondering which pattern to choose: standard radio buttons solution, or something a little more sophisticated but not too uncommon—switchers.

I know there are some flaws regarding the use of switchers, e.g. problems with the state of the switcher, but maybe merging standard switcher with indicator of the state (active/inactive) would be the best solution.

I have attached an image with some ideas, such as those implemented in Apple and Google products. So is the switcher a better solution than radio buttons?

[image: Switchers]

Comment: Don't forget about a single checkbox. Switches are probably more readily compared to a checkbox than to radio buttons.

Comment: Radio buttons should not be used for Boolean (Yes/No) answers. Checkboxes are more suitable for such purposes.

Answer (score 5):

There is a very good thread on this topic [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/should-a-toggle-button-show-its-current-state-or-the-state-to-which-it-will-chan).
A must-read in my view when designing or considering switches.

Summary: often-used designs for switches (including the standard iOS designs) are not very good. **They fail to communicate clearly if they are in ON-state or in OFF-state**.

A good switch design tells the user if it is ON or OFF:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS43UG.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Interestingly: the only design in your question that passes the test is the radio button design. In the other designs it is only clear that switch is ON because you have a similar one in the OFF-state next to it. In reality, this is not always the case.

Quick user test you could do: take 1 switch (not 2 of the same version) and ask the user “do you think this switch is on or off?” My bet: the radio button would score best.

Switches look nicer, and make for more intuitive touch control, but I would advise to use a good design, where it is clear that it is an interactive thing, but also that communicates if it is ON or OFF.

Comment: I've seen the last one example you posted in Google privacy q form it's quite good.

Comment: Is that an image in Comic Sans on a site dedicated to UI/UX?

Comment: Haha, if I remember correctly I used the default tool (balsamic) with its default font. Disclaimer: the picture is a sketch, not a pixel perfect design. No advice is intended on font, colors, sizes, line styles, corners, shadows etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Generalization of interface elements is not working. It is high depended on the context**

Switches are not working well if you have more than two options. If you have on/off active/inactive; switches can have better results.

Radio buttons can be used with more options. If you have three options or more; radio buttons show better results.

Comment: Thanks, I've only two options - on/off, but I'm wondering if a little bit older users follow this switcher pattern or maybe they're much more familiar with the standard and more common radio buttons.

Comment: Switch has higher Skeuomorph level than radio button so better way but only if you have two options.

Comment: check links for guidelines for windows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465475.aspx  and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700395.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a very ;) good idea to use a platform's default widgets as much as possible (and as long as they serve your design's purpose), because users are typically well-acquainted with them.

You write that you want to allow your users to un-/select individual items from a list.

If you're designing for a desktop or web app, using good old checkboxes might already do the trick, and it's a simple, effective, and non-ambiguous solution.

On mobile devices, using the On/Off radio button pair is tricky, because iOS does not feature radio button widgets out of the box, and it might look out-of-place on that platform, too.

Alternatively you could use switches, but especially for long lists, they can look a bit "heavy."

That said, iOS also "officially" supports using checkmarks for selecting multiple options from a list, as you can see in the screenshot (from the Clock app) below, and this is also an [established Android/Material Design control](https://material.io/design/components/selection-controls.html#checkboxes), so that could be a viable approach for your app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The risk with radio buttons on mobile is that can be set with an accidental touch. That's why apple didn't create radio buttons for iOS.

They changed that interaction to a subtle swipe over the control.

Kind regards :)

Comment: You don't need to swipe the iOS control, you can just touch it to change its state.

Answer (score 0):

Switches are intended for, as the name suggests, switching the state of something on/off (or similar).

Radio buttons are intended for making a single choice from a list of options.

Your use case is a perfect fit for using switches. Take care when implementing them to follow best practices and avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

The case is so simple it all depends on the number of options to pick from:

**2 options** go for the **Switcher**

**3 - 5 options** go for **Radio button**

**> 5** go for a **List or Combo**

**Note: Sometimes the List or the combo can hold more than one option depending on the need and how you configure it**