# Caret symbol for collapsed and expanded vertical left menu

Tags: gui-design, navigation, user-behavior

What is the UX behind the caret symbol used when a left menu is collapsed?
Some applications use the left caret and some use the right. What's the ideal approach?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Toggles will always be confusing, as explained by others:

- https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/1321/84675
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2721066

As the learning curve is small, the best thing to do is make a consistent choice that works for the visual hierachy of your UI:

- All icons represent the current state
- All icons represent the action on click

Answer (score 1):

The icon used in the Patterns– [Navigation drawer](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#), Material Design Guidelines, for the action of collapsing a left menu is that left caret you mentioned.

[image]