# Windows vs. Linux file managers: Sorting triangles point in opposite directions?

Tags: sorting, sort, files

- Windows Explorer's sorting triangles: ▼ Larger and newer files first.
- Various Linux file managers: ▼ Smaller files first. ▲Larger files first.

Why is there possibly that distinction? And which one is more suitable and less confusing?

I prefer the way Windows Explorer does it, because the long edge of the triangle (representing larger files) is on the side of the larger files.

In Linux, the upper side should probably represent the tip of a mountain. But I still prefer the representation of Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perhaps an oversight based on the way the items are sorted. When I'm using of designing sort arrows, I think of it as `ascending` or `descending`, and this would be applicable to both text, date, and numbers.

By this logic, `^` means ascending; if you were to sort alphabetically, it would go from `A -> Z`, dates from `old -> new`, and sizes from `small -> big`. I cannot test how the Linux file managers use the arrow, but if the ascending icon is only reversed for file sizes, it would seem to be a bug.

Comment: If Linux _consistently_ uses `^` and `v` the "wrong way round", it could (pure speculation) be because the symbol shows _what you get when you click this button_, whereas Windows shows _what you've got now_. Somewhat like the debate over On/Off toggle buttons: should you show what you've _got_, or what you _get_ if you click the button (see [Should a toggle button show its current state or the state to which it will change?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/1318/57088))