# Should I use multiple icon for two states of toggle button

Tags: buttons, toggle

I have a simple bar chart component and I'm going to add a button which help user able to switch between two view modes. Let say:

- First mode called "relative view" (show percentage value of each column).
- Second mode called "absolute view" (so actually number value of each column).

The button to toggle-like, but I want the UI is just a simple button, not using the switch. Default is "absolute view".

I have two questions:

- Should I use two different icons for each state according the current view mode? For example, one "number" icon, and one "%" icon.
- If I use two different icons, the icon should be show according the "current state" or "next state"?

For second question, for example if I am currently in "absolute view", should it be displayed "number" icon or "%" icon? Each way has its meaning I think:

- If I use icon for next state, that mean I taught user: click to change to next state.
- If I use icon for current state, that mean I taught user: this is the current state, click to toggle.

This thing makes a little considering. Any help should be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So you already have seen the issues with using one button. The answer is to have 2 separate buttons and it will be clear which one is active.

Comment: Two separate buttons take more space, that's the problem. And I thought that a toggle button is enough for toggling job :-?

Comment: I highly recommend you visit this page: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/should-a-toggle-button-show-its-current-state-or-the-state-to-which-it-will-chan?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from the bottom.

> If I use two different icons, the icon should be show according the "current state" or "next state"?

- [Should a toggle button show its current state or the state to which it will change?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/should-a-toggle-button-show-its-current-state-or-the-state-to-which-it-will-chan)
- [Should an icon show current state or next state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716729/should-an-icon-show-current-state-or-next-state)

> Should I use two different icons for each state according the current view mode? For example, one "number" icon, and one "%" icon.

In the case of media player, I'd say two icons is safe because "play - pause" is expected by most users. However in your specific case it depends on the fact whether your users expect the "relative - absolute" pair.

In other words, if they see a "relative" button, do they expect it will also help them going to a "absolute" view?

> The button to toggle-like, but I want the UI is just a simple button, not using the switch. Default is "absolute view".

I'm not sure if this violates your requirement but I think it's safer to go with something like this, as all buttons and icons are always there:

[image: button group image]

In fact, the toggle/switch may not really future-proof. If you want 1 button, you may also go with a Select widget which allow you in the future to add more view options if necessary (for example, "Relative", "Absolute", "Hybrid")

**To summarize, I think it's better to show all the options and their states instead of switching between them.**

Comment: Perfect reference and thanks for your answer :D

Answer (score 1):

What is described in the question is a change of view. There's a generic icon for "view mode" that changes the type of arrangement of the elements in a list:

[image]

In this case it would be to find a single icon of mode change from "absolute" to "percentage" and make it understandable:

[image]

About the default view it depends of the type of project, I don't think it's simple to answer without knowing it.

<sub>*</sub><sub>*Icons from [thenounproject.com](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=view%20mode)*</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer for my first question. And how about the second one? I'm still on considering.

Comment: I put something about the default view at the end of the answer

Comment: No, my second question is about next or current state. The default view is depended on my business, that's not my question.