Which toggle pattern is better?
My design team disagrees about the best toggle experience. The toggle is meant to authorize a client. I will leave it at that to avoid influencing any responses. Which one do you prefer, and why?


I recommend reading this: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/should-a-toggle-button-show-its-current-state-or-the-state-to-which-it-will-chan/40954#40954

why do you have checkboxes besides toggles (or buttons)? Checkboxes should be enough

Both options are valid. What needs to be considered is whether they are being understood.
When using the switch component from option 1, it’s always important to show what is marked. Since the component already has what it represents at the top of the table (authorized), just indicate its status as yes/no or on/off.
In the case of option 2, simple and explanatory words would be a perfect choice, such as yes/no and active/inactive.
Sorry for the English.

Curious:
Authorized: Enabled/Disabled
or
Authorized: YES/NO
I have found that the Toggles options above canwork as long as you include the label inside the component(some users still have issues discerning when it is ON or OFF..
Hope this helps.

in my opinion, for the needs with this goal, the button text should be “authorization” when you activate the button it will become “authorized” aka become the selected status. in my opinion it will make the user easier to understand because the text in the button is to the point.
whereas if you use a toggle you also need to add a text description to the toggle, when the state has not been authorized and which has been authorized. and that will also make it easier for users to understand because the text in the button is to the point.
both are good to use, only in my opinion less to the point on its purpose.

It should just use checkboxes

From material design (they call toggles switches):

Checkboxes should be used instead of switches if multiple, related options can be selected from a list. Checkboxes visually group similar items effectively and take up less space than switches.




